Can't get UltiSnips to work on Vim
Ive been trying to get the plugin https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips to work, but I am continiously getting the following error when trying to use the function :UltiSnipsEdit:
AttributeError: type object 'PathFinder' has no attribute 'find_module'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: initialization of vim raised unreported exception
AttributeError: type object 'PathFinder' has no attribute 'find_module'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: initialization of vim raised unreported exception
línea   11:
AttributeError: type object 'PathFinder' has no attribute 'find_module'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\aleja\vimfiles\plugged\ultisnips\pythonx\UltiSnips\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from UltiSnips.snippet_manager import UltiSnips_Manager
  File "C:\Users\aleja\vimfiles\plugged\ultisnips\pythonx\UltiSnips\snippet_manager.py", line 11, in <module>
    import vim
SystemError: initialization of vim raised unreported exception
Se ha detectado un error al procesar function UltiSnips#Edit:
línea    6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'vim' is not defined

Ultimately, I think that what matters is the last line: NameError: name 'vim' is not defined.
I have tried:

Uninstalling UltiSnips
Upgrading Python

What I know:

UltiSnips is installed, as commands like :help UltiSnips work.
Vim can use Python3, as :echo has('python3') returns 1.
Other plugins have been working so far, so it is not a probem related to installation.

Another problem that I have is that I cannot edit any file, as trying to write will result in UltiSnips raising the following error:
Se ha detectado un error al procesar InsertCharPre Auto-órdenes para "*"..function UltiSnips#TrackChange:

or
NameError: name 'UltiSnips_Manager' is not defined

I don't know that more to do. Any help is appreciated.

Use the plugin's issue tracker.

What is the result of :py3 print(sys.version)? What is the result of :py3 import vim?

@VivianDeSmedt the first one returns the systems python version (as expected), but the second order raises an ‘AttributeError: type object  ‘PathFinder’ has no attribute ‘find_module’’. Ultimately, a SystemError

Looks like a bug in UltiSnip. I can't reproduce it at my end. I suppose you should report it in the UltiSnip issue tracker. If you tell us more about the exact version of Vim (i.e. :version output) and the exact version of Python you are using (i.e.: py3 print(sys.version)) we could have a second chance to reproduce it :-)

Or even the Vim issue tracker. It doesn't look OK that :py3 import vim fails.

@VivianDeSmedt okey thank you, I will now report it to the plugins GitHub. thank you for your help!

find_module has been removed as of python 3.13 and therefore in Vim 9.1.417

@ChristianBrabandt okey, maybe that is the issue, I am now installing python 3.12

Please don't edit the solution into your question, self-answer instead or accept one of the existing answers (only one at the moment), if they work for you.

@Friedrich I cant accept the answer since it is a comment, but I auto answered myself

I was able to fix it thanks to @ChristianBrabandt comment, since 'PathFinder' was removed in Python 3.13. Installing Python 3.12 fixed the problem.
